# Navigation to a speical part of the content by using href="#contentId" does not working in Blazor Web Assembly pages

Tags: c#, bootstrap-5, blazor-webassembly

I am a learner of Blazor. I want to make a menu navbar and navigate to each menu in the same page, but the navigation doesn't working.

I have no idea what have blocked the navigation. Can someone give a suggetion to solve this issue?

Here are my navbar codes:

```
<div class="topnavbar">
    <nav id="navbar-topmenu" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light px-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-underline">
            @if (SQL.menus.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, MainMenu> m in SQL.menus)
                {
                    if (m.Value.Disabled == false)
                    {
                        string menuname = m.Value.Name.ToString();
                        int menuid = m.Value.ID;
                        <li class="nav-item" style="list-style-type: none; margin-top: 1em">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="SelfServiceOrder/#menucontent+@menuid">@menuname</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul>       
</div>
```

Whatever links I clicked bring me to the top of the page rather than the menu position. However, if I input the link url to browser e.g. (https://localhost:7280/SelfServiceOrder/#menucontent+6) and try to access it, it bring me to the correct position.

Click any links in the navbar will show the url in the browser and bring me to the top of the page. In this situation, if I try to select the url and press enter without any modification, it will cause a page reload and doesn't go to correct position. But if I change it to any other menu number, it works.

The reason why I using the path name here is because if I use href="#menucontent+@menuid" that is used in anchors tutorial, it bring me to (https://localhost:7280/#menucontent+6) that is not the correct page.

Answer (score 1):

Intra page navigation is not supported in Blazor as of now. You can use JSInterop to invoke javascript that scrolls the element into the view / focus.

*However* support for hashed routing has been added in .net 8. I suggest you switch to .net 8 preview and use it straightaway:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#hashed-routing-to-named-elements

Comment: Thank you!. I will try but my project is based on an old project with .Net Core 3.1. Upgrade the .Net Version in the past attempts lead variant issues that take a long time to solve, so I will consider to solve this on current environment at first.